# Static dropdown is not working correctly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Can someone tell me why **Public class dropdown** is not working, I mean program is not selecting value from static dropdown.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class new_class
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**Sterownik Dla Firefox */
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Log in to your customer account']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id= 'email_create']")).sendKeys("Piccolo666x2@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='SubmitCreate']//span")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id_gender1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("Mario");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customer_lastname']")).sendKeys("Kowalski");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds
    }

    public class dropdown {
        public void main (String[] args)
        {
            Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='days']")));

            s.selectByValue("2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do step by step? You have an inner class with non-static main method. What is the idea behind this approach?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you are running this file.

Observe that *dropdown* is an inner class. If you run the *new_class.java* solely, it will execute *new_class.main* method. To run *dropdown.main*, you have to call `java packageName.new_class$dropdown`.

However, if you want to run the new_class' main method and afterwards the dropdown main, you can just create separated files and instantiate an object.

On new_class.java:

```
public class new_class
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**Sterownik Dla Firefox */
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Log in to your customer account']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id= 'email_create']")).sendKeys("Piccolo666x2@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='SubmitCreate']//span")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id_gender1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("customer_firstname")).sendKeys("Mario");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customer_lastname']")).sendKeys("Kowalski");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait for maximum 10 seconds

        // Selecting on dropdown
        new dropdown(driver).selectSecondDay();
    }
}
```

On dropdown.java:

```
public class dropdown {

    public void dropdown(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void selectSecondDay () {
        Select s = new Select(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='days']")));
        s.selectByValue("2");
     }
}
```

OBS: The code is not aligned with several naming conventions of the Java language - I would suggest you to [take a look at them](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and refactor your names.